# Where shall I put the main.cpp in Visual Studio? Into the Resources or into the Sources Folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The titles contains the question.

In general could someone tell me the difference between those two folder?

Comment: Resources is for things like images or text or menus or dialogs.

Comment: Those are filters and have nothing to do with folders or file location. The filters are made so you can find things easier. You can add and remove filters as you feel like and put any file in any filter, it makes no difference to Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Especially the information that it actually makes no difference was important for me. Because I like it more having the header files and their bodies next to each other. (Like I understood this thing with the filters is as well true for the header folder).